# Drawing a paraboloid with a rounded rectangle cross-section

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, 3d

The question explains it all, I'm looking for an equation that allows me to draw a paraboloid in 3D space with a rounded rectangle cross section across each value of Z.

The full explanation is as follows: I'm trying to make an app with a UI similar to that of the apple watch UI. The way that is done in [this guide](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/apple-watch-home-screen-ui-animation/) is by using an upside down paraboloid as the falloff for the size of the icons. Which leads to a size distribution across the screen that looks like this: [image: Circle cross section]

With the brightness value (0-->1) indicating how much icon would be scaled  by if it were in that location. As you can see, because screens are rectangular, there is a lot of empty space in the corners I wish to get rid of.

I want something more like this:

[image]

Where the corners are more filled out (the straighter the rectangle the better of course)!

I've looked up equations, but all I could find was something that looked like a pyramid. That has a linear falloff. I want a shape that is curved like a paraboloid but with the cross section of a rounded rectangle. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Update:** I tried Aretino's answer, and Aretino's answer with Rahul's suggestions and had some beautiful results. In the end though, I used Nominal Animal's response as the shape was just so clean and the falloff stretched to the corners of the rectangle, which I thought was very cool.

Here is what it looks like in a 3D Graph ($C_c = 0.9$):

[image: 3D Plotting of the graph]

and here is what it looks like in practice in the app ($C_c = 1$):

[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: Try with $z = -c((x/a)^4 + (y/a)^4) + 1.0$. If that's not flat enough, you can raise the exponent to $6$ or $8$.

Comment: For a parabolic falloff with the same rounded rectangle cross-section use something involving $\bigl((x/a)^4+(y/a)^4\bigr)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Aretino, I shamelessly stole your suggestion, and added it into my answer. Feel ffree to post your own answer (use the images if you wish). I personally found the differences in corner behaviour between our suggestion very interesting. I have no idea which one works best, as I think it is something for UI/UX testing to find out. :)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Your answer is fine for me. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ be the width and $H$ be the height of your screen, $C_C$ a curvature exponent, $C_{MIN}$ being the minimum scaling factor ($0$), and $C_{MAX}$ the maximum ($1$). Then, the scaling factor at $(x, y)$ is
$$C(x,y) = C_{MIN} + ( C_{MAX} - C_{MIN} ) \left ( \frac{ 16 x y ( W - x ) ( H - y ) }{ W^2 \, H^2 } \right )^{C_c}$$

With $C_c = 1/2$, the factor is overall high, and only drops near the edges. With $C_c = 2$, the factor changes $C^2$-smoothly to the edges (that is, even the rate of change changes smoothly).

[image: Contours for C_c = 0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]

---

@Aretino's suggestion as a comment to the question produces more "rectangular" shape, with corners having larger minimum scaling areas. Using the above definitions, (but with $C_c = 4$ or $C_c = 6$ per Aretino's suggestion), it is
$$C(x,y) = C_{MAX} - (C_{MAX} - C_{MIN}) \left ( \left ( \frac{2 x - W}{W} \right )^{C_c} + \left ( \frac{2 y - H}{H} \right )^{C_c} \right )$$

[image: Aretino's scaling function with exponent 4 and 6]

---

@Rahul suggests further in a comment that taking the square root of the right parenthesized part in Aretino's suggestion yields parabolic falloff.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you mind sharing how did you learn/get this equation?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees: I remembered playing with something similar at one point. I started up Gnuplot, with `set xrange [-1:1]; set yrange [-1:1]`. I recalled that to get close to the corners, I multiplied the coordinate terms, and since it should be symmetric wrt. origin, I tried $x^2 - 1$ and $y^2 - 1$ as the coordinate terms. That gives `splot (x*x-1)*(y*y-1)`. To adjust the falloff, I tried various values of `n`: `n = 0.25 ; splot ((x*x-1)*(y*y-1))**n notitle`. For the graphs, I used `unset surface ; set contour base ; set view 0,0 ; unset xtics ; unset ytics`, and merged them in Gimp. [...]

Comment: [...] That gave the function in the $(-1,-1)-(+1,+1)$ range. So, I fired up Maple, told it `c := (x, y) -> C_MIN + (C_MAX - C_MIN)*((x^2-1)*(y^2-1))^C_c;` and asked `simplify(c(2*x/w - 1, 2*y/w - 1), size);` which Maple said is `(C_MAX-C_MIN)*(16*x*(w-x)*y*(h-y)/w^2/h^2)^C_c+C_MIN`, which I just wrote in my answer. It was fast, visual, and easy, and scratched that mental itch (*"hey, I think I've seen this before; now, what was it exactly?"*) that I get with interesting questions. (I like Gnuplot, because it is free/open, and lets me rotate the 3D plots visually.)

Comment: (And to clarify, by *"playing with something similar"*, I do believe it was early experiments with `putpixel(x, y, color(2*x/w-1, 2*y/h-1))` with `color(u, v)` being a function that returns an RGB color for $-1 \le u, v \le +1$, using VESA graphics under DOS (I even had a printed copy of Ralf Brown's Interrupt List...) This was sometime in the early nineties, when I got my first true-color graphics card.)

Comment: Oh wow haha.. I just thought you were messing around with something similar a few weeks ago. Thanks so much again!